# Remove all axis values and labels in twoord plot

Tags: r, plot, axis, overlap, plotrix

I want to remove all the axis including x, left and right y but retain the boundary of the plot.
I tried to set `xaxt` and `yaxt` to `'n'` but no luck.

```
library(plotrix)

twoord.plot(2:10,seq(3,7,by=0.5)+rnorm(9),
        1:15,rev(60:74)+rnorm(15),
        type=c("bar","l"), 
        xaxt='n',
        yaxt='n')
```

Is there any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so from what I saw. It's easy enough to create this plot anyway:

```
library('plotrix')
set.seed(1)
x1 <- 2:10
y1 <- seq(3,7,by=0.5)+rnorm(9)
x2 <- 1:15
y2 <- rev(60:74)+rnorm(15)

par(mfrow = c(1, 3), mar = c(3, 3,2,3))
twoord.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, type=c("bar","l"), xaxt='n', yaxt='n', mar = c(3, 3,2,3))

## to recreate
plot(x1, y1, type = 'n', xlim = range(x2), ylim = range(y1))
rect(x1 - .4, 0, x1 + .4, y1, col = 'black')
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x2, y2, type = 'l', col = 'red', axes = FALSE)
axis(4, col.axis = 'red')

## again with no axes
plot(x1, y1, type = 'n', xlim = range(x2), ylim = range(y1), axes = FALSE)
rect(x1 - .4, 0, x1 + .4, y1, col = 'black')
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x2, y2, type = 'l', col = 'red', axes = FALSE)
box()
```

[image]