# Add units to Y axes

Tags: r, plot, visualization, plotrix

I'm using `plotrix.twoord` to compare two plots in a single graph using this code:

```
library(plotrix)

mempool<-read.csv("mempool-size.csv")
mempool$date <- as.Date(mempool$date)
fees<-read.csv("transaction-fees.csv")
fees$date <- as.Date(fees$date)

twoord.plot(mempool$date,mempool$value,fees$date,fees$value,type="b",
            ylab="Unconfirmed transactions (B)",rylab="Fees paid per day (BTC)",
            main="Fees and mempool size since 2017",
            )
```

This prints a graph like this:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xuK3.png)

This looks almost right but the left axis looks a bit odd. I would like it to show the unit (B) after the values - preferably with metric prefixes instead of scientific notation (20MB instead of 2e07B).

I'm not sure if plotrix.twoord provides an option like this, so I tried to use ggplot instead:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=fees, aes(x=date, y=value), color='black') + 
  geom_line(data=mempool, aes(x=date, y=value), color='red')
```

But now the fees line is just flat because it doesn't have it's own axis.

You can find the data here if you want to try it yourself:
http://www.sharecsv.com/s/07076796191d9e414e5b50840d9ed7ad/mempool-size.csv
http://www.sharecsv.com/s/72a183dd3ab0df781eacbfee81999548/transaction-fees.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotrix does not seem to support self provided tick mark labels, there are a few ways around this.

1) The easiest way is to divide the left axis values by 10^6

```
mempool$value <- mempool$value / 1000000
twoord.plot(mempool$date,mempool$value,fees$date,fees$value,type="b",
            ylab="Unconfirmed transactions (MB)",rylab="Fees paid per day (BTC)",
            main="Fees and mempool size since 2017",
            )
```

2) You could use base R without plotrix, e.g.

```
plot(mempool$date,mempool$value, type='b',ylab="Unconfirmed transactions", yaxt='n',xlab='Date')
axis(2, c('0MB', '20MB', '40MB', '60MB', '80MB', '100MB', '120MB', '140MB'), at=seq(0, 140*10^6, length.out=8))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(fees$date,fees$value,type="b",col="red",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="", ylab='')
axis(4)
mtext("Fees paid",side=4,line=3)
```

3) You could hack the twoord.plot function to remove one of the axes, and then just add it afterwards similar to option 2) above. For details of this, see [Handling axis with dates in twoord.plot (remove axis 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558470/handling-axis-with-dates-in-twoord-plot-remove-axis-3)